# Getting NaN when I think I'm creating a string

Tags: javascript, string, nan

```js
let studentScore = 90
let totalPossibleScore

let gradeMessage = function(studentScore, totalPossibleScore = 100) {
  let finalGradePercent = (studentScore / totalPossibleScore) * 100

  if (finalGradePercent >= 90) {
    let letterGrade = 'A'
    return letterGrade

  } else if (finalGradePercent >= 80) {
    let letterGrade = 'B'
    return letterGrade
  } else if (finalGradePercent >= 70) {
    let letterGrade = 'C'
    return letterGrade
  } else if (finalGradePercent >= 60) {
    let letterGrade = 'D'
    return letterGrade
  } else {
    let letterGrade = 'F'
    return letterGrade
  }
}

let studentScoreMessage = `You got a ${gradeMessage(studentScore, totalPossibleScore)} (${studentScore/totalPossibleScore}%)!`
console.log(studentScoreMessage)
```

---

the response:
`You got a A (NaN%)!`

Why isn't it giving me the letter grade?

Comment: `totalPossibleScore` is a top-level variable declaration which is never initialized. It's also the name of a function parameter, but using the same name is misleading because they're not the same binding.

Comment: got it got it.  Thanks! Been stuck on this for the last 40 mins

Answer (score 1):

`totalPossibleScore` is not initialised. Try:

```
let totalPossibleScore = 100
```

In your function:

```
function(studentScore, totalPossibleScore = 100) {
    let finalGradePercent = (studentScore / totalPossibleScore) * 100
```

Since the global `totalPossibleScore` is initialised by default to `undefined`, the argument `totalPossibleScore = 100` will initialise `totalPossibleScore` to 100, thus the function will appear to return the correct answer.

Back in the main code, you have:

```
let studentScoreMessage = `You got a ${gradeMessage(studentScore, totalPossibleScore)} (${studentScore/totalPossibleScore}%)!`
```

In the second expression we have:

```
${studentScore/totalPossibleScore}
```

Which is:

```
${90/undefined)
```

Which is:

```
NaN
```

Thus you get `NaN` in brackets.

Comment: "Since NaN is greater than any integer" no it isn't, this is misleading. NaN is not comparable to any number

Comment: OK, I've totally rewritten that as it was all wrong! Should be correct now.